# Horizontal scroll jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with my horizontal scroll. When I inspect in chrome I don't see errors. Could you tell me where is the problem because I can't find it ?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $('#right-button').click(function() {
        $('#content').animate({
        marginRight: marginRight -"200px"
        }, "fast");
        });
        $('#left-button').click(function() {
        $('#content').animate({
        marginLeft: marginLeft +"200px"
        }, "fast");
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #browser {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
    ​
</head>
<body>
    <div id="browser">
        <a href="#" id="left-button">BACK</a>
        <div id="content">
            This is the content of the text which should be scrolled.
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="right-button">NEXT</a>
    </div>
    ​
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to `marginRight` which isn't a variable defined in your page.

Replace

```
$('#content').animate({
    marginRight: marginRight -"200px"
```

by

```
$('#content').animate({
    marginRight: "-=200"
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with
>   a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is
>   computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current
>   value of the property.

There is another logical problem if I guess your intent : you can't play like this with both left and right margin. See the [**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hubz/) to see what can work.

Comment: There was another (logical) problem. See the [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9hubz/).

Answer (score 0):

A JSFiddle in the future please:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/P7HvH/

Also, you cannot add strings like you are doing:

```
marginLeft +"200px"
```

Add integers first... then append strung suffix:

```
(marginLeft + 200) + "px";
```

Also, your example doesn't define a `marginLeft` variable.  Add this to the top:

```
var marginLeft = 10;
```

Comment: Sorry, my jsfiddle is uptodate now.  Sorry about that.  My working example changed a couple things just to show it working.  I assume you can get it from there.